# Minimal distance in Dynamic Time Warping with Librosa

Tags: python, matlab, audio, matrix, librosa

When using the Librosa library to compute the Dynamic Time Warping matrix between two time series, how does one obtain the minimum distance between the two signals? In [Matlab](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/dtw.html) the first returned argument is this distance. In [Librosa](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.core.dtw.html) the returned value is the accumulated cost matrix, with the comment that 'D[N,M] is the total alignment cost.'

Does this mean that the bottom right entry of the D matrix is the minimum distance between the two time series, like the return value in Matlab? If not, how do I obtain the distance from the returned matrix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The total cost is the accumulated cost at the last point on the optimal path, so:

```
D, wp = librosa.dtw(X, Y)
best_cost = D[wp[-1, 0], wp[-1, 1]]
```

Depending on the matching mode, the path may not end at `D[-1, -1]`.